# Can I condense the coding within this .get() event handler?

Tags: jquery

I need to collect a large amount of data from a single page, but in doing that, I feel the code required to do this could be condensed and simplified.

Can I condense this code even more, or is this as condensed as it can get?

```
$.get('/blog.html', function(data){

      // Post Titles
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(1) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-1");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(2) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-2");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(3) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-3");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(4) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-4");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(5) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-5");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(6) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-6");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(7) .blog-title").appendTo(".ticker-7");

      // Post Images
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(1) img").appendTo(".ticker-image-1");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(2) img").appendTo(".ticker-image-2");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(3) img").appendTo(".ticker-image-3");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(4) img").appendTo(".ticker-image-4");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(5) img").appendTo(".ticker-image-5");

      //Post Dates
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(1) .date").appendTo(".ticker-date-1");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(2) .date").appendTo(".ticker-date-2");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(3) .date").appendTo(".ticker-date-3");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(4) .date").appendTo(".ticker-date-4");
      $(data).find(".blog-post:nth-of-type(5) .date").appendTo(".ticker-date-5");

});
```

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single loop by relating the index of the current `.blog-post` to the target `.ticker-N` element, something like this:

```js
$.get('/blog.html', function(data) {
   $(data).find('.blog-post').each(function(i) {
     var $blog = $(this), index = i + 1;
     $blog.find('.blog-title').appendTo('.ticker-' + index);
     $blog.find('.img').appendTo('.ticker-image-' + index);
     $blog.find('.date').appendTo('.ticker-date-' + index);
   });
});
```

Comment: This is phenomenal -- works beautifully! Thank you very much, @Rory McCrossan! Is there a way to add in another class here: .appendTo('.ticker-' + index, '.title-' + index);?

Comment: Glad to help, and sure: `appendTo('.ticker-' + index + ', .title-' + index)` Note that this will effectively make another clone of the element and put it in the `title-N` element

Comment: I knew some unfamiliar arrangement of apostrophes was key. Exactly what I needed, plus more, @Rory McCrossan. Thank you again!